# Is this result about the floor function true?

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I want to know if the following result is true or not.

> Prove that for all positive integer $n$, $$\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+2}}\right\rfloor \leq \sqrt{n}$$

---

I drew a graph of $$f(x)=\sqrt{n}-\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+2}}\right\rfloor$$ on desmos, and it seems that not all of $f(x)$ is positive, but at integer $x$ it indeed seems to be non negative. However I'm not sure if it's true for all integer $x$ and I haven't been able to prove it.

Comment: (Minor typo) The function $f(x)$ doesn't involve $x$ so ...

Comment: @TianVlašić Not quite sure your hints are that helpful. $\sqrt{n}$ isn't an integer. EG $\lfloor \sqrt{2} + 1 \rfloor > \sqrt{2}$. If I'm mistaken, please let me know.

Comment: @Calvin Lin You are right. $\epsilon < 1$ does not necessarily imply $\left \lfloor{x+\epsilon} \right \rfloor = \left \lfloor {x} \right \rfloor$.

Comment: Depending on the definition of "used eventually". For example, I don't need to use $ \lfloor x \rfloor \leq x$ for a specific $x$, but given that it is true of the floor function in general, maybe the proofs of the properties use it. (EG That's like saying "we must eventually use $1+1 = 2$ in any arithmetic")

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\sqrt{n } + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+2} } = \frac{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+2}}{2}$.
While this is easy to verify, it might not have been an obvious guess/observation.

**Another hint:** If $a < b$, then $ \lfloor a \rfloor \leq \lceil b \rceil - 1$.
This follows because $\lceil b \rceil - \lfloor a \rfloor$ is an integer and is positive, hence is $ \geq 1$.

**Corollary:** The result follows

> $\sqrt{n } + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+2} } < \sqrt{n+1}$

> $ \lfloor \sqrt{n } + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n+2} } \rfloor \leq \lceil \sqrt{n+1} \rceil - 1 \leq \sqrt{n}$
>  This uses $n$ is an integer. It is not true for all real $n$.

Equality holds when $n$ is a perfect square.
(This follows from the above, but shouldn't be a surprise. It is necessary as the RHS is an integer. It is also easy to check that this is sufficient.)

Comment: the another hint, that is If $a<b$ then $⌊a⌋≤⌈b⌉−1$, is it an if and only if statement? Like if I prove $⌊a⌋≤⌈b⌉−1$, then we would get $a<b$?

Comment: What do you think? Can you find a counter example? EG Is if possible that $b < a$ but the property still holds?